# How is (0|1|...|n) handled as a DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

How is n-times regex alternation operation, e.g. (0|1|...|n), handled in a DFA (MYT algorithm)?

Here are the rules for the MYT also (Converting Regular Expressions to NFAs
):
https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article shows how to get a FA for the regexp `0 + 1`: make a FA, $M_0$, for `0`, make a FA, $M_1$, for `1`, make a new start state state, $q_0$, and link it to the original start states of $M_0$ and $M_1$ with $\epsilon$-moves.

Then recognize that the regexp `0 + 1 + 2` is `(0 + 1) + 2`, so do the construction again, using the FA for `0 + 1` and the FA for `2`. Rinse and repeat.